# `:!mutt -f some.mbox` works with Vim 8.1 but returns `No recipients specified` in NeoVim 0.3.1

Tags: vim, neovim, mutt

The mutt command-line switch `-f` is for "specifying which mailbox to load". For example, the following command loads the MBOX-format file `some.mbox`:

```
$ mutt -f some.mbox
```

(Added:) I can run this from the Vim 8.1 command line with: `:!mutt -f some.mbox`.

However the same command, when run within NeoVim 0.3.1 (was: *within a shell script or on the vim command line*) returns: `No recipients specified.`

I have tested this both on MacOS and Linux machines.  Searching the Web for many variants of `mutt no recipients specified` has turned up no clues.

I have a Vimscript function that searches the current line for the pathname of an MBOX-format file (eg, `/Users/foo/some.mbox`) and calls up that file in mutt - but only when run within Vim 8.1, not within NeoVim.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `printf '#!/usr/bin/env sh\nneomutt -f $MAIL' > mutt.sh && chmod +x ./mutt.sh && ./mutt.sh`. What version of `neomutt` are you using? I have `NeoMutt 20180716` here.

Comment: Works for in `mutt` with `:!mutt -f some.mbox`. What is `:mutt`?

Comment: @phd Sorry - that should be `:!mutt -f some.mbox` or `:!neomutt -f some.mbox` - corrected above.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I am using `NeoMutt 20200424` on MacOS.

Comment: I see now that the problem lies not with `mutt` or `neomutt`, but with `/usr/bin/vim` (8.1), which works, versus `/usr/local/bin/nvim` (0.3.1), which does not.  Will edit the description above.